# MaxMind GeoIP redirect users from a country with one IP allowed

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, geoip, maxmind

I am using MaxMind and want to redirect users from a country with only IP allowed from the country.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^XX$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example based on IP2Location in our server. It redirect based on IP 8.8.8.8 & country is US.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^US$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^8\.8\.8\.8$ RewriteRule ^(.*)$
http://www.website.com/$1 [R,L]
```